# ConsoleOutput formatting vs TextFile formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, format, text-files

I have a string builder that i am generating and when i display it in the console, it is formatted perfectly:

[image]

but when i attempt to export the stringbuilder.ToString() to a text file, the formatting gets lost in translation:

[image]

```
foreach (var item in companyList.Keys)
            {
                reportForText.AppendLine(item.ToString());

                foreach (var user in companyList[item])
                {


                        reportForText.Append(String.Format("\n{0,-22}: ", user.Name));
                        foreach (var group in user.GroupList)
                        {
                            reportForText.Append(String.Format("{0}\n", group).PadRight(25 + group.Length));
                        }
                    }
                }
                reportForText.AppendLine();
                reportForText.AppendLine();
            }
```

Comment: Seems like this is a lack of using `\r`, `\n` and/or `\t`, and instead trying to build a string manually with whitespace in some way?

Comment: Is there any code involved in any of this? Mind sharing it? "Here's some text and here's some other text. They differ". Thanks, that's interesting. What do you want me to do about it?

Comment: _"the formatting gets lost in translation"_ -- no, not really. You didn't "format" the text in the first place, except to include characters in the output that when presented in a very _specific_ scenario, result in the layout you want. You can minimize or even eliminate differences between output scenarios by using spaces instead of tabs, always using `"\r\n"` for line-breaks, and always using a fixed-space font. But ultimately, the visual appearance of your data will always depend to some extent on what software you're using to display it.

Comment: @gravity has the right idea. Notepad.exe does not support `\n` as a newline, it only supports (as far as I know) `\r\n` as a newline. You can fix this by using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n` for a new line (or even using `\r\n` directly). You should be able to open your current file in another editor and it should look fine even though it only has `\n`'s in it. Also note your formatting is relying on a fixed-width font. If you view your output in Word with Calibri font for example the spacing won't line up perfectly as you see in notepad or the console.

Comment: @Quantic that fixed it...thank you...if you want to post as an answer, I will select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad.exe does not support `\n` as a newline, it only supports (as far as I know) `\r\n` as a newline. You can fix this by using [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `\n` for a new line (or even using `\r\n` directly): "A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms". These days it's not a "Windows or Unix or Mac" thing because as you see it's dependent on the program itself and what characters it has defined to represent "new lines", so IMO this is a question about Notepad.exe and how it works and it *should* be irrelevant if you are on Unix or non-Unix, despite the language support for `Environment.NewLine`. This is corroborated by the Windows `Console` itself supporting `\n` as a newline even though it's a "non-Unix" platform.

An unrelated issue you might run into is the font being used. Both Notepad.exe and Console by default use fixed-width fonts, so all your spacing currently lines up. But if you change to a variable width font then your colons and stuff will stop lining up perfectly.